# Swiper zoom doesn't work in desktop version, but it works on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

this is the code

```js
var mySwiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  allowTouchMove: false,
  zoom: {
      maxRatio: 2,
      minRatio: 1
  },
})

mySwiper2.zoom.enable();

$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
    mySwiper2.zoom.in();
})
$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
    mySwiper2.zoom.out();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-zoom-container" data-swiper-zoom="2">
                <img src="http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png" id="pop_op_IMG">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try do something but doesn't work, I don't have idea what is de problem.

If somebody could help-me...

Comment: Probably too obvious, but have you checked the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is working, but you need to double click the picture to zoom.